# How to install ReportingServicesTool when executing Powershell script via Azure DevOps Pipeline Build

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops

I have attempting to create a Powershell script that allows me to connect to a remote SSRS server and upload/download RDL files. 
This script is intended to run during the build on my Azure DevOps TFS server.

I am working behind a company proxy, I have admin rights on the TFS server, and currently, the build is only executing the Powershell script but it always fails to install the module.

This is my most current attempt.

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

Install-PackageProvider NuGet -MinimumVersion '2.8.5.201' -Force -Confirm:$false -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name ReportingServicesTools -Scope CurrentUser

    $reportServerUri = 'http://ReportServer1.asmx?wsdl,http://ReportServer2.asmx?wsdl'

    FOREACH ($ReportServer IN $reportServerUri.Split(",")){
        $ServerName = ([System.Uri]$ReportServer).Host.ToUpper()
        #Try to setup Proxy
        TRY{
            $proxy = New-RsWebServiceProxy -ReportServerUri $ReportServer
        }CATCH{
            Write-Host " > Error Setting Proxy - $_. Skipping"
            Continue
        }
        write-host $proxy
    }
```

I expect the ReportingServicesTools to be installed, then iterate over the report servers, connecting to each one and output the details of each proxy (Currently a very code to test connections), but in order to do that it needs to install NuGet PackageProvider, however, this always fails and provides me with the following;

```
2019-08-19T05:41:46.6172426Z WARNING: MSG:UnableToDownload «https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409» «»
2019-08-19T05:41:47.7338745Z WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
2019-08-19T05:42:28.6550883Z WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
2019-08-19T05:42:31.7740864Z Install-Module : NuGet provider is required to interact with NuGet-based repositories. Please ensure that '2.8.5.201' 
2019-08-19T05:42:31.7743172Z or newer version of NuGet provider is installed.
```

Or sometimes;

```
2019-08-19T04:07:40.9172188Z Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package 
2019-08-19T04:07:40.9174833Z provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
2019-08-19T04:07:40.9175648Z At D:\agent.LIS\_work\6\s\Common\TestAutoDeploy.ps1:7 char:1
```

And once or twice;

```
2019-08-19T04:13:41.1175526Z Install-NuGetClientBinaries : Exception calling "ShouldContinue" with "2" argument(s): "Windows PowerShell is in 
2019-08-19T04:13:41.1177412Z NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available."
```

Would anyone be able to provide me some information on whether this is possible, and if so, how do I go about getting it to work?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you able to install ReportingServicesTool when execute Powershell script directly on remote build agent instead  through build pipeline? This will help to narrow down if the issue related to environment or not.